# Querying Data Backward in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple question regarding oracle sql. So i have this table

```
WEEKNUM DATA
1       10
2       4
3       6
4       7
```

So i want to make a view that shows like this,

```
WEEKNUM DATA ACCUM_DATE
1       10   10
2       4    14
3       6    20
4       7    27
```

I spend hours on this simple one but couldnt get any luck

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT weeknum, 
       data,
       sum(data) over (order by weeknum) accum_data
  FROM your_table_name
```

should work.  I'm using the `sum` analytic function here and assuming that you want to start with the smallest `weeknum` value and keep increasing the running total as the `weeknum` values increase.  I'm also assuming that you never want to reset the accumulated sum.  If you're trying to do something like generating an accumulated sum that restarts each year, you'd want to add a `partition by` to the analytic function.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Cross JOin` in this case

Query:

```
select 
A.WEEKNUM
, A.DATA
, SUM(B.DATA) DA
from table1 A
cross join table1 B
WHERE A.WEEKNUM>=B.WeekNUM
GROUP BY A.WEEKNUM
, A.DATA
order by A.WEEKNUM
```

Result:

```
WEEKNUM DATA    DA
1   10  10
2   4   14
3   6   20
4   7   27
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys but i just found out this method works perfectly,

```
OVER (ORDER BY WEEKNUM ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CUMULATIVE_WEIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a sub-select to calculate:

```
select WEEKNUM, DATA, (select sum(DATA) from tablename t2
                       where t2.weeknum <= t1.weeknum) as ACCUM_DATE
from tablename t1
```